# Export specified selection of charts as image to different .ppt slides

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

What I am trying to do is exporting a selection of charts to different PowerPoint slides as images. When I try to export a single chart, it works, but selecting more than one and trying to export them again doesn't work.

What am I missing? 
down below is the code I tried so far to solve my issue.

```
Sub SendTop2ChartsToPPT()
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim pptShpRng As PowerPoint.ShapeRange
Dim lActiveSlideNo As Long
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim ChartSh As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim fName As String

Set ChartSh = Worksheets("Graphs")
FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
fName = "Report Top2 (" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mmm") & ")"
On Error Resume Next
Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error Resume Next
If pptApp Is Nothing Then
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add
    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(pptPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
Else
    If pptApp.Presentations.Count > 0 Then
        Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation
        If pptPres.Slides.Count > 0 Then
            lActiveSlideNo = pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
            Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides(lActiveSlideNo)
        Else
            Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(pptPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
        End If
    Else
        Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add
        Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(pptPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    End If
End If
ChartSh.Shapes.Range(Array("Top2SiteVisits", "Top2SiteShare")).Select
Set ChtObj = Selection.ShapeRange.Group
ChtObj.CopyPicture

    With pptSlide
        .Shapes.Paste
        Set pptShape = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        Set pptShpRng = .Shapes.Range(pptShape.Name)
    End With

    With pptShpRng
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Height = pptPres.PageSetup.SlideHeight
        .Width = pptPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth
    End With

    With pptPres
        .SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & fName & ".pptx"
        .Close
    End With

    pptApp.Quit
    ChtObj.ShapeRange.Ungroup
    Set pptSlide = Nothing
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The powerpoint part of the script is fine and will work.

When it comes to charts, I'd advise against dealing with the Shapes, but rather just use the `ChartObjects` collection - The `ChartObject` is the container that holds the actual `Chart` on the Worksheet.

I'm not completely sure by what you mean with "selecting" Charts to send over to ppt and why you would want to deal with a `ShapeRange` array and deal with Shape groups and such, but let's say you have a bunch of Charts on one sheet, you select a number of them and wish to copy-paste them to powerpoint as pictures: The following does exactly that, with a new slide for each chart.

```
Sub SelectedChartsToPPTSlide()
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add

For Each ChtObj In Selection 'Will error if your selection includes other shapes and such.
    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(pptPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    ChtObj.Chart.CopyPicture
    pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial
Next ChtObj

Set pptSlide = Nothing
Set pptPres = Nothing
Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

In the same way you can loop over the `ChartObjects` within a worksheet:

```
For each ChtObj in Worksheets("Graphs").ChartObjects
    If ChtObj.Chart.Name = "Some name here" Then
        'Do stuff with that chart
    End If
Next ChtObj
```

Hope this helps.

N.b. If you need to manipulate the picture on the powerpoint slide, you can capture it using `Set pastedPictureShape = pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)` right after the `PasteSpecial`